# Some explanation about calling PHP function in class

Tags: php, class, zend-framework

I know it is basic php question but I had something that I didn't understand, it is about the `return;` when I call a function, the bellow code is just an exemple.

**Case :** In `TEST2` when I do my check then I return, that `return;` do the job and stop the execution of the next code `TEST3` Good.

Now in `TEST1` I Call a function  `_checkThat()`, and this function do a check then redirect. the problem is it returns shure but the next code will also be executed `TEST2` and `TEST3` Why ? why when I put the content of that function directly in `TEST1` it returns and stop the execution of next code ?

```
<?php class Some_Class_IndexController extends Some_Other_Controller_Front_Action
{
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'); //Output: "john"
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email'); //Output: "john@gmail.com" 
    $phone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('phone'); //Output: 09000000       

    //TEST1
    if(isset($name)) {
        $this->_checkThat($name);
    }

    //TEST2
    if(isset($email)) {
        if($email === "john@gmail.com") {
            //some code to redirect to another page
            return;
        } else {
            //some code to redirect to another page
            return;
        }
    }

    //TEST3
    if(isset($name)) {
        $this->_checkthat();
    }

    private function _checkThat($name) {
        if ($name !== "john") {
            //some code to redirect to another page
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Other question, Can I use `continue;` in this case :

```
if(isset($name)) {
    Mage::log('check passed'); //This just write in logs
    continue; // or something else
} else if (!isset($name)) {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Your `Some_Class` isn't a valid PHP class. it has a lot of code outside of the method, which you can't have. Please show us a proper example.

Comment: Yes, I know but it's not a problem, it's instead the inside logic that is important, My class works fine

Comment: The posted class can't work fine. It would throw syntax errors. If you want logic in a class, the logic _must_ be inside methods. When asking us for help, you need to give us a proper and testable example.

Comment: I told you that my class works fine, this is just an example, anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: __Not working__ example is a bad example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as already mentioned in comments your example code is not correct, your problem here:

```
if(isset($name)) {
    $this->_checkThat($name);
}
```

is that you **do nothing** with result returned by `_checkThat()`. And obviously you should **`return`** it:

```
if(isset($name)) {
    return $this->_checkThat($name);
}
```

As a sidenote, I should mention that naming methods with `_` to mark them `protected`/`private` is out-of-date practice since php5.

Comment: okey, so `return $this->_checkThat($name);` instead of `$this->_checkThat($name);` will work correctly and stop exection of the next code, which is logic right ?

Comment: `return` in function __ends__ function execution.

Comment: Thank you, that was well the return in calling the function `return $this->_checkThat($name);` and not `$this->_checkThat($name);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple guide.

> **Inheritance – reusing code the OOP way**

Inheritance is a fundamental capability/construct in Object oriented programming where you can use one class, as the base/basis for another class or many other classes.

**Why do it?**

Doing this allows you to efficiently reuse the code found in your base class.

Say, you wanted to create a new `employee class` since we can say that `employee` is a type/kind of `person’, they will share common properties and methods.

**Making some sense?**

In this type of situation, inheritance can make your code lighter because you are reusing the same code in two different classes. But unlike `old-school` PHP:

You only have to type the code out once.
The actual code being reused, can be reused in many (unlimited) classes
but it is only typed out in one place conceptually, this is sort-of
like PHP includes().

Take a look at the sample PHP code:

```
// 'extends' is the keyword that enables inheritance
class employee extends person 
{
    function __construct($employee_name) {
        $this->set_name($employee_name);
    }
}
```

> **Reusing code with inheritance:**

Because the class `employee` is based on the class `person`, `employee` automatically has all the public and protected properties and methods of ‘person’.

Nerd note: Nerds would say that `employee` is a type of person.

The code:

```
class employee extends person 
{
    function __construct($employee_name){
        $this->set_name($employee_name);
    }
}
```

Notice how we are able to use set_name() in `employee`, even though we did not declare that method in the `employee` class. That is because we already created set_name() in the class `person`.

Nerd Note: the `person` class is called (by nerds,) the `base` class or the `parent` class because it is the class that the `employee` is based on. This class hierarchy can become important down the road when your projects become more complex.

> **Reusing code with inheritance:**

As you can see in the code snippet below, we can call get_name on our `employee` object, courtesy of `person`.

The code:

```
<?phpinclude("class_lib.php"); ?>
    <?php
        // Using our PHP objects in our PHP pages. 
        $stefan = new person("Stefan Mischook");
        echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();

        $james = new employee("Johnny Fingers");
        echo "---> " . $james->get_name();
    ?>
```

This is a classic example of how OOP can reduce the number of lines of code (don’t have to write the same methods twice) while still keeping your code modular and much easier to maintain.

> **Overriding methods 1**

Sometimes (when using inheritance,) you may need to change how a method works from the base class.

For example, let us say set_name() method in the 'employee' class, had to do something different than what it does in the `person` class.

You `override` the `person` classes version of set_name(), by declaring the same method in `employee`.

The code snippet:

```
<?php
    class person 
    {
        protected function set_name($new_name) {
            if ($new_name != "Jimmy Two Guns") {
                $this->name = strtoupper($new_name);
            }
        }
    } 

    class employee extends person 
    {
        protected function set_name($new_name) {
            if ($new_name == "Stefan Sucks") {
                $this->name = $new_name;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Notice how set_name() is different in the `employee` class from the version found in the parent class: `person`.

<**Overriding methods: 2**

Sometimes you may need to access your base class’s version of a method you overrode in the derived (sometimes called ‘child’) class.

In our example, we overrode the set_name() method in the `employee` class. Now I have 
 used this code:

```
hperson::set_name($new_name);
```

to access the parent class’ (person) version of the set_name() method.

The code:

```
<?php
    class person 
    {
        // explicitly adding class properties are optional - but 
        // is good practice
        var $name;   
        function __construct($persons_name) {
            $this->name = $persons_name;
         }

         public function get_name() {
            return $this->name;
         }

         // protected methods and properties restrict access to 
         // those elements.
         protected function set_name($new_name) {
             if ($this->name !=  "Jimmy Two Guns") {
                $this->name = strtoupper($new_name);
             } 
         }
    } 

    // 'extends' is the keyword that enables inheritance
    class employee extends person 
    {
        protected function set_name($new_name) {
            if ($new_name ==  "Stefan Sucks") {
                $this->name = $new_name;
            }
            else if ($new_name ==  "Johnny Fingers") {
                person::set_name($new_name);
            } 
          }

        function __construct($employee_name) 
        {
            $this->set_name($employee_name);
        }
    }
?>
```

Notes: Using the symbol:

```
::
```

… allows you to specifically name the class where you want PHP to search for a method:

`person::set_name()`
… tells PHP to search for set_name() in the `person` class.

There is also a shortcut if you just want refer to current class’s parent – by using the `parent` keyword.

The code:

```
protected function set_name($new_name) 
{   
    if ($new_name ==  "Stefan Sucks") {
        $this->name = $new_name;    
     }  
     else if ($new_name ==  "Johnny Fingers") {
        parent::set_name($new_name);    
    }   
}
```